# How to parse ReadableStream for a POST request?

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I am trying to create some basic crud operations using the new [Nextjs 13 route handlers](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/route-handlers) along with Prisma using TypeScript.

This is what my POST request handler looks like:

```js
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const clientData: clientToCreate = req.body;

  try {
    const data = await prisma.client.create({
      data: clientData,
    });
    return NextResponse.json(data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return NextResponse.error(e);
  }
}
```

Here the req.body is `ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null` and I can't find out how I can parse it in order to access the data inside of it. When I try to do req.body.json() i get: `Property 'json' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>'`.

Here is my how I cosntruct my request:

```js
interface ApiRequest {
  url: string;
  method: "GET" | "POST" | "PUT" | "DELETE";
  params?: Object;
}

const getRequestUrl = (url: string) => {
  return `${process.env.BASE_API_URL}/${url}`;
};

const defaultHeaders = {
  Accept: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

export const apiRequest = async (request: ApiRequest) => {
  return await fetch(getRequestUrl(request.url), {
    headers: defaultHeaders,
    method: request.method,
    body: request?.params ? JSON.stringify(request.params) : undefined,
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
      throw e;
    });
};
```

Then all I do is use postman in order to send a POST request with the excact same headers as the ones you see above. Is my request wrong? I can't figure out what the mistake is.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To get the body content:

```
const body = await request.json()
```

If you use request.body it returns a ReadableStream Object

Comment: THANK YOU. I did not want to have to do the conversion myself, looks annoying (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream).